# Как создать папку если ее нет в Delphi 10?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Как создать папку на С диске если ее нет и в ней создать файл если его нет. Если они есть - просто открыть для записи.

Answer (score 1):

Тут только вопрос фантазии

Пытается создать директорию: `CreateDir(Path):boolean;`

Пытается создать директорию только не помню точно чем отличаются: `MkDir(Path):boolean;`

А эта типа берёт ломик и создаёт если у выше перечисленных не получилось ну и насколько помню именно она может создавать рекусрсивно пути(пока не будут существовать все директории из пути): `ForceDirectories(Path):boolean;`

Comment: Ещё можно вообще изобрести велосипед и заюзать консоль

Comment: SPar := '/K MD'+Path;
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'cmd.exe', PChar(SPar), nil, SW_SHOW);
Юзая ShellApi

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Более правильно использовать классы со статическими методами модуля System.IOUtils:

```
TDirectory.Exists('full_path_to_dir');
TDirectory.CreateDirectory('path_to_dir');
```

Пример использования по вопросу:

```
if not TDirectory.Exists('C:\Folder')
then TDirectory.CreateDirectory('C:\Folder');
if not TFile.Exists('C:\Folder\file.txt')
then TFile.Create('C:\Folder\file.txt');
```

TFile.Create возвращает поток TFileStream, с которым можно продолжить работать дальше.

Там есть много чего другого полезного.